# Log4j 2 version upgrade - question for Windows event logging ( win32eventlogappender.dll generation)

Tags: log4j2

I'm working on log4j version upgrade. I see log 4j 2 is not supporting NETEventLogger. So I added log4jna dependency for Windows event logging and it needs win32eventlogappender.dll to be on the classpath. Can someone please tell me how to generate win32eventlogappender.dll ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found it in the package when I downloaded Log4JNA jar.